# Accessing member objects from another member object within the same class

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following C++ code:

```
class Circuit {
    public:
    Properties circuit_prop;
    Library tech_libray;
    InstanceList instances;
}
```

`Properties`, `Library` and `InstanceList` are classes defined in my code. And for example the class `InstanceList` has a member function called `build`. Is it possible to access the member object `circuit_prop` or `tech_library` without passing them as parameter to `build`? What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because an `InstanceList` could just as well exist outside of `Circuit`.

If you have a method that needs to access various members, it should go into the class that has those members - in your case, `Circuit`.

Alternatively, `InstanceList` needs to know the `Circuit` it belongs to, in which case it can access the members via `Circuit`'s public interface.

Comment: Maybe the best approach would be to pass a pointer to `Circuit` object to `InstanceList` constructor (and save it for later accesses)

Answer (score 1):

Just because classes are associate members of the same class does not mean that they can freely access each others member objects. I would say making `circuit_prop` and `tech_library` members of `InstanceList` would be better than having them all members of the same class. This way you can get `Circuit` to access them freely from a `get` `set` set up or by making `Circuit` a `friend class` of `InstanceList`

Answer (score 1):

circuit_prop or tech_library scope is within the class Circuit only, better make a method inside Circuit that has all the public access you need for separate classes.